# Component infinite Re-renders, when passing new Date().toISOString() to <Query variables />

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, prisma

### EDIT:

If I replace the variable with a hardcoded string like so:

```
<Query
          query={CLASSES_QUERY}
          variables={{ startsAt_gte: "2019-01-11T11:11:11.111Z" }}
        >
```

all work just fine.

---

---

The component which contains `<Query />` keeps re-rendering when the `variables` are provided with `new Date().toISOString()` to startsAt_gte Prisma field.

First this didn't happen at all. Then few days ago, the  just stopped working (started infinite re-render).

Moving `new Date().toISOString()` 
from `<Query variables={..} />` component 
to `constructor()` function in React class component solved for one component.

**However,** the issue still persists here: 
*(possibly elsewhere too)*

```
import React from 'react';

import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

import Loading from 'loading';
import Error from 'error';

const CLASSES_QUERY = gql`
  query CLASSES_QUERY($startsAt_gte: DateTime) {
    classes(where: { active: true }) {
      id 
      }
      sessions(where: { startsAt_gte: $startsAt_gte }) {
        id
        startsAt
      }
    }
  }
`;
class ClassList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startsAt_gte: new Date().toISOString()
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { startsAt_gte } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <Query
          query={CLASSES_QUERY}
          variables={{ startsAt_gte: startsAt_gte }}
        >
          {({ data, loading, error }) => {
            if (loading) return <Loading />;
            if (error) return <Error />;

            return (
              <div>
                <div>
                  {data.classes.map(cls => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <h2>{cls.title}</h2>
                        {cls.sessions.map(ses => {
                          return <div>{ses.startsAt}</div>;
                        })}
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassList;
```

Am I doing something wrong in the code above?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you have `variables={{ startsAt_gte: startsAt_gte }}`. Wouldn't you just need to reference `startsAt_gte`?